# Laravel dynamic routes to controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-blade

I currently have a dynamic routes:

```php
Route::get('/companydetail/{id}/{slug}', function ($id, $slug) {    
    $listings = Company::find($id);    
    $badges = Company::find($slug);    

return view('pages.mycompany', compact('data','repository','title','listings','category', 'badges', 'list', 'slug'));
});
```

Everything works fine. 
BUT, I would like to have this dynamic in pages controller

```php
Route::get('/companydetail/{id}/{slug}','mycompanydetailController@create');
```

```php
public function mycompanydetail() {
  return view('pages.mycompanydetail',compact('data','listings', 'badges', 'list', 'slug'));
}
```

How should I transform from dynamic routes to pages controller?

Comment: From where data repository title are coming ?

Comment: You can ignore 'title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Route::get('/companydetail/{id}/{slug}', 'PagesController@companyDetail');
```

Now, in your controller like this:

```
public function companyDetail($id) {

    $listings = Company::find($id);

    return view('pages.companydetail', compact('listing'));
}
```

In this way, you can add further variables.

Comment: I think we are close to the solution. But I get error  "Undefined variable: id"

Comment: @RogaMen It's pleasure. Good Luck Man